# Randomly limiting number of features QGIS displays for specific point layer?

Tags: qgis, select, display

I have a map with various point layers (e. g. shops, bars, hotels). Some of these contain many features and the map is overcrowded – particularly in urban areas.

Hence, I would like to (randomly) reduce the number of displayed features for specific layers (ideally not by changing the underlying data).
This is possible for labels (`Limit number of features to be labeled to...` and `Discourage labels from covering features` in the `Layer Properties` under `Labels` -> `Rendering`).

Basically I am looking for an option such as: “Limit number of features to be shown to...”

What I have:
[image]

What I want (e. g. limited to 5 displayed shopping-features):
[image]

Comment: Dou you really want a random number of features, or any selectable but fixed number?

Comment: Thanks for your reply and effort, @user30184! I want a random number of features in the sense that there is no attribute in the data to differentiate the ones QGIS should display and the ones omitted from the map. I do not care which features are selected and displayed. Nonetheless, you are right. It would be beneficial to set a fixed number. Like in my example: Limit the number of shopping-features to be shown to 5 in order to make the map easier readable (so if I pan the map to a region where only 5 shopping facilities are I expect QGIS to display all of them).

Comment: You might like point clusters https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gNL-ZSlc4KM

Comment: Nice! Thanks for the hint @user30184! I was not aware of this new QGIS 3.0 feature and just checked it out. In most situations I’d say this solves the “limit number of features displayed” problem and is a great addition to the QGIS tools. But in my case I want to retain the exact position of a feature and simply not show all features.
Maybe as an example: Someone wants to know where a shopping-facility is. He/she neither wants to see the location of all shops in the town (single symbol) nor does he/she wants to know that there are X shops in this region (point cluster).